Django/Heroku - Handling ObjectDoesNotExist Exception When Pushing Data from API to Django Database
My django application receives data from an API.
It's very unlikely the API will send incorrect information, but I am trying to cover the possibility the API may send data that would return ObjectDoesNotExist from malicious attempts.
Below is my try at how I could handle the exception, by leaving the data 2 tries. After that, I want it to stop pushing the data.
I left a few print statement to track the tries are being executed. But none of them are getting printed. This makes me think that the data received from the API is considered as valid (because it exists) and its only when the data is pushed to the database that the application realises it does not exist.
Any suggestion on how I could handle this? (I am hoping I am clear)
models:
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

class ItemisedLoyaltyCard(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="venueitemisedloyaltycard")
    add_points = models.DecimalField(name = 'add_points', null = True, blank=True, default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=5
    
    def __str__(self):
        ret

the function:
def API_data(request):
    userprofile_id = request.GET.get('userprofile_id', '')

    venue_id = request.GET.get('venue_id', '')

    user = UserProfile.objects.get(id=userprofile_id)

    venue = Venue.objects.get(id=venue_id)

    venue_loyalty_point_rule = VenueLoyaltyPointRule.objects.get(venue=venue)

    scans = ItemisedLoyaltyCard.objects.filter(
        user_id=user.id, venue=venue)

    is_point_valid = loyalty_card_validation_rule(
        scans, user, venue, venue_loyalty_point_rule)

    if is_point_valid:
        try_count = 0
        max_retries = 2  # Define the maximum number of retries
        while try_count < max_retries:
            try:
                ItemisedLoyaltyCard.objects.create(
                    user_id=user.id, venue=venue, add_points=venue_loyalty_point_rule.points)
                # If creation succeeds, set data and break the loop
                data = {'points': venue_loyalty_point_rule.points, 'user': user.id, 'venue': venue.name,
                        'success': is_point_valid, 'frequency_rule': venue_loyalty_point_rule.frequency}
                break
            except ObjectDoesNotExist: <!-- This part is not showing getting printed-->
                try_count += 1
                print("Retrying...")
        else:
            # If max retries exceeded, set error message in data
            print("Max retries exceeded. Unable to create loyalty card entry.")
            data = {'error': 'Max retries exceeded. Unable to create loyalty card entry.'}
    else:
        print("Invalid loyalty card validation rule.")
        data = {'error': 'Invalid loyalty card validation rule.'}


    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")


Show us how you created the models.

@Ghazi, just added the models. Curious to know why you are asking :)

I am seeing a conflict here, you are trying to create ItemisedLoyalityCard object inside try statement, yet, your exception indicate that you are checking if that object does not exist?

perhaps, are you trying to check an existing object here? or did you forget to use get method to check the object after creation in try statement?

I am trying to create an object, that's correct. However, when creating this object, I also need to make sure the foreign key I am creating this object exists (in this case say venue_id). This is in the case the API would provide some data to the applictaion with a venue_id that doesnt exist and end up with a recurring push for the applicaion to create an object with an innexisting venue_id. By doing this I want to limit the number  of "ObjectDoesNotExist" error to two before stopping the push to the database. Does that make sense? (thanks for sticking around! @Ghazi)

let me get this right , you have the venu_id as foreign key, and you want to check if it exist or not, if it doesn't exist, then you raise ObjectDoesNotExist? but why is it limited to twice only?

Yes, the API sends data to the application but cannot be sure the venue_id exists when it is sent. So I need to check if the ID actually exists.  If not, the application will keep pushing data and return an ObjectDoesNotExists error for ever. The amount of retries could be 1, 2 or 3.. I just set an arbitrary number. Does it answer your question?

I have answered your question, hope it helped!

Thanks! Somehow I didnt get any notification of your answer.

Here is a workaround to your API to handle venue existence in the application.

def API_data(request):
    userprofile_id = request.GET.get('userprofile_id', '')

    venue_id = request.GET.get('venue_id', '')

    user = UserProfile.objects.get(id=userprofile_id)
    
    try:
    
      # first we check if venu id actually exist
      venue = Venue.objects.get(id=venue_id)
      venue_loyalty_point_rule = 
      VenueLoyaltyPointRule.objects.get(venue=venue)

      scans = ItemisedLoyaltyCard.objects.filter(
        user_id=user.id, venue=venue)

      is_point_valid = loyalty_card_validation_rule(
        scans, user, venue, venue_loyalty_point_rule)
      if is_point_valid:
         ItemisedLoyaltyCard.objects.create(
                    user_id=user.id, venue=venue, add_points=venue_loyalty_point_rule.points)
                # If creation succeeds, set data and break the loop
         data = {'points': venue_loyalty_point_rule.points, 'user': user.id, 'venue': venue.name,
                        'success': is_point_valid, 'frequency_rule': venue_loyalty_point_rule.frequency}
      else:
        print("Invalid loyalty card validation rule.")
        data = {'error': 'Invalid loyalty card validation rule.'}
                    
                
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
      # code flow continue here if venue id does not exist
      print("Retrying")
      



   return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")



Note that i have disregarded the retrying count system that you implemented, simply because there is no point in retrying the attempt of creating another new object of ItemisedLoyalityCard, if venue still doesn't exist.
Hope that helped!
